# Validate Forms using Javascript on the email input field

Tags: javascript, forms, email

Please i am trying to specify a pattern in the email input field in my form that it takes on lowercase words and if uppercase words are inputted in the email field it give an error and the form isn't submitted.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with javascript.

```js
function checkText(e) {
  const text = e.target.value;
  if (text && (text === text.toUpperCase() || text.substr(-1) === text.substr(-1).toUpperCase()))
    console.log('No upper case allowed')
}
```

```html
<input type="text" oninput="checkText(event)">
```

[Working FIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0y9hLmv6/)